# Profiling CPU with NanoFramework and Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, iot, nanoframework

Is it possible to attach to an ESP32 while debugging and profile memory usage on Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition?

Answer (score 1):

No. Profiling memory usage from Visual Studio is not supported in nanoFramework VS extension.